# Powershell script to print file-path of every file in a folder

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have 2 folders: 'Old' and 'New'. Most of the files from 'Old' have been copied to 'New'. However, the structure of the sub-folders in 'Old' and 'New" are different. So the file-path for a file in 'Old' is very different from its copy in 'New'.

I need to loop through each file in 'Old', search for that file in 'New', and write the old and new file-paths for each file to a text file.

I have been assigned to do this manually, but it will take a long time due to the number of files. So I want to write a script. I am new to Powershell and am having difficulty figuring out which cmdlets can help me with my task.

I will appreciate any kind of guidance. Thank you.

Comment: I used this to try to print the fullname/path of all files in 'New' to a text document: 
'ForEach ($file in Get-ChildItem -recurse){$file.fullname | out-file output.txt}'

However, this just writes the path for only 1 file.

Comment: you would want to do ``foreach ($file in $(gci -recurse)) {$file.fullname >> output.txt}`` or you could use ``Out-File -append``. What happens there it only outputs one file since it everytime overwrites whatever you've written to that file.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I am now trying to figure out how to retrieve the name of each file, search for it in C:\Old , and append the path(fullname) to output.txt

Comment: try to fetch the file names from _old_ and _new_ to seperate variables (e.g. `$filesInOldFolder =  dir folderToOldFiles -r | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }  | select Name`). Afterwards you can use `Compare-Object` to get the difference between files in old and new folder (e.g. `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $filesInOldFolder -DifferenceObject $filesInNewFolder`

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this

```
#list old files
$patholdfile="c:\temp"
$listoldfile=Get-ChildItem $patholdfile -File -Recurse | select Name, FullName

#list new files
$pathnewfile="c:\temp2"
$listnewfile=Get-ChildItem $pathnewfile -File -Recurse | select Name, FullName

#extract liste file old and name and search all file in newlist
$resultsearch=@()
foreach ($currentfile in $listoldfile)
{
    $resultsearch+=New-Object  psobject -Property @{
    Name=$currentfile.Name 
    OldPath=$currentfile.FullName

    #if you want the firt founded uncomment this and comment after
    #NewPaths=($listnewfile | Where {$_.Name -eq $currentfile.Name} | select FullName -First 1).FullName 

    NewPaths=($listnewfile | Where {$_.Name -eq $currentfile.Name} | select FullName).FullName -join "~" 
    }

}

#export result in csv file
$resultsearch | select name, OldPath , NewPaths | export-csv -Path "c:\temp\result.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```